# How to add a button that deletes an item from the list in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm making an input field that outputs a list
I would like, please, how to create a function that clears the list I have entered or deletes a specific item from the list.

```
let eleValue;
let myItems = [];

let handleChange = (e)=>{
    eleValue = e.target.value;
}

let handleForm = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    myItems.push(eleValue);
    e.target.elements[0].value = "";
    render()
}

let removeList =()=>{

}

let render = ()=>{
    let ele = (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleForm} action="">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" />
                <input type="submit" />
                <button onClick={removeList}>remove</button>
                <ul>
                {myItems.length? myItems.map((item)=>
                    <li>{item}</li>
                ):''}
            </ul>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    )
    ReactDOM.render(ele, document.getElementById('app'))
}
render();
```

Comment: Where is `myItems` defined?

Comment: @smac89 let myItems = [];
An empty array that is filled in by an input field and then output in a list

Comment: You need to add `myItems` to your component's state. That's the only way any updates done to it will be reflected in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, define the array of content with objects:
`const myItems = [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}]`

The id is used to check which item you will delete.

After have the array, you can pretty much use `filter` in javascript to strip the item from the array.

[filter in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
// my set of items
const myItems = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3}
];

// choose the id to delete
const idToDelete = 2;

// new array of items without the item with id 2
const myNewItems = myItems.filter((item) => item.id !== idToDelete);

console.log('old set of items', myItems)
console.log('new set of items', myNewItems )
```